# Mutiple consecutive outputs instead of one in a function in PHP

Tags: php, function, scope, static-variables

I am learning about `static` variables in PHP and came across this code in PHP manual.

```
<?php
function test() {
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    $count--;
}
?>
```

I couldn't understand the purpose of last `$count--;`. So, I wrote a different version of the function below:

```
<?php

function test() {
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;

    echo $count;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    echo 'I am here!';

    $count--;
}

test();
?>
```

The output of above code is:

```
12345678910I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!I am here!
```

Why isn't the output just the line below because we go past the `if` condition only once.

```
12345678910I am here!
```

If we are going past the `if` condition multiple times, then shouldn't the output be:

```
1I am here!2I am here!3I am here!4I am here!5I am here!6I am here!7I am here!8I am here!9I am here!10I am here!
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more about recursion than static variables. However:

Why the numbers are written out first and the text afterwards? Let's break each run of the function. For simplification, I'll only use example with 2 calls (`if ($count < 2)`)

- 1st call starts, `$count` is incremented to 1

  - **prints `1`**
- Within the 1st call, the condition `$count < 2` is met, so it calls `test()` (so that's going to be the 2nd call)
- 2nd call starts, `$count` is incremented to 2 (if it weren't static, it wouldn't keep the value from the higher scope)

  - **prints `2`**
- Within the 2nd call, the condition `$count < 2` is NOT met, so it skips the `if` block

  - **prints `I am here!`** and ends the 2nd call
- Now the 1st call is done running the recursive function so it continues

  - **prints `I am here!`** and ends the 1st call

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `test()` within the method that doesn't stop the execution of the rest of the code in the method.

The reason, as far as i can see, it doesn't output a number after each string of "i am here" is because you're calling the method `test()` before the output. So each time it's waiting for that method to complete before moving on to the next string.

If you were to move the `$count` echo to after it I believe it'd output as expected.

Does that answer your question at all?